# According to Protestant understanding, how does a believer know if they have been called to be an evangelist?

Tags: protestantism, evangelism, discernment, calling

An evangelist is a specific office that is **different** from pastors & teachers.

**Q: According to Protestantism, how does one know if they have been called to be an evangelist?**

> “He who descended is Himself also He who ascended far above all the
> heavens, so that He might fill all things.) And He gave some as
> apostles, and some as prophets, and **some as** **evangelists**, and some as
> pastors and teachers, for the equipping of the saints for the work of
> service, to the building up of the body of Christ;” ‭‭Ephesians‬
> ‭4:10-12‬

Comment: Related: [How do Christians discern if they are being called by God to ministry, and what ministry specifically?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83881/50422)

Answer (score 2):

**According to Protestantism, how does one know if they have been called to an evangelist?**

The very same way that one may know any part of what the Lord calls them to and gifts them for:

> I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye **present your bodies a living sacrifice**, holy, acceptable unto God, which is your reasonable service. And be not conformed to this world: but be ye transformed by the renewing of your mind, **that ye may prove what is that good, and acceptable, and perfect, will of God.**

The degree to which we deny ourselves and offer our bodies as a living sacrifice unto the Lord (think [whole burnt offering](https://www.bible.com/bible/1/LEV.1.1-17.KJV)) is the degree to which we have clarity viz a viz our calling.  Discerning and carrying out our stewardship of this new life in Christ is not primarily an intellectual exercise...we walk by faith and not by sight.

Comment: So the particular believer who’s been called to be an evangelist, starts to see God working that way?

Comment: @Cork88 And to feel especially compelled (impelled) in whatever particular direction one is being called: 1 Corinthians 9:16.